# pyFluidsynth 'module' object has no attribute 'Synth'

Tags: python, audio, fluidsynth

I have both fluidsynth

```
sudo apt-get install fluidsynth
```

and pyfluidsynth

```
sudo pip install pyfluidsynth
```

installed.

However, when I run the standard import commands, I get the following error:

```
>>> import fluidsynth
>>> fs = fluidsynth.Synth()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Synth'
```

Comment: What happens if you do `print fluidsynth.__version__`?

Comment: >>> fluidsynth.__version__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'
>>> dir(fluidsynth)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For whatever reason, it appears as if following your installation directions made you download fluidsynth version 0.2, instead of version 1.2.4, which is the most recent one.

To install the correct package, uninstall fluidsynth and manually install the correct package (the tar.gz file from the pypi page for [fluidsynth](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyFluidSynth)):

```
pip uninstall pyfluidsynth
pip install -Iv https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyFluidSynth/pyFluidSynth-1.2.4.tar.gz#md5=60079310701d0b9298b65a8b6728ffcc
```

Comment: Thanks!  That helped!  dir(fluidsynth) now returns functions!  I'm still getting errors, but they appear to be with JACK not fluidsynth installation anymore: ```>>> fs.start()
Cannot use real-time scheduling (RR/5)(1: Operation not permitted)
JackClient::AcquireSelfRealTime error```

Comment: It's because he probably did `pip install fluidsynth`, which is another package. `pip install pyfluidsynth` should be working fine.

Comment: As Valentin Radu noted, there is a dead package named fluidsynth (2012).  If you had installed the old fluidsynth, the fix is to `pip uninstall fluidsynth`.  Even though I had done `pip install pyfluidsynth`, because pyfluidsynth asks for an import of fluidsynth, the old package gets is.  Why is pyfluidsynth importing fluidsynth???  Why is fluidsynth still around, as there is no homepage anymore???

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem with fluidsynth installation. I followed the following steps in Windows:

- Install pyfluidsynth: `pip install git+https://github.com/0xf0f/pyfluidsynth`
- Go to the path where fluidsynth has been installed: Ex.: `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages` and open `fluidsynth.py` file.
- In the line of `fluidsynth.py` where it is written `lib = find_library('fluidsynth')` add  `find_library('libfluidsynth64')`
- Now download [libfluidsynth64.dll](https://github.com/fkortsagin/Heretic-Shadow-of-the-Serpent-Riders-Windows-10/blob/master/libfluidsynth64.dll) and paste it in the path where you have fluidsynth installed: Ex.: `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages`

You can test if it works by running `python`, `import fluidsynth` and `fuidsynth.Synth()` in the Anaconda Prompt.