# How to fix module 'fluidsynth' has no attribute 'Synth'

Tags: python, ubuntu, fluidsynth

## What I have tried

1. I've installed `pip install pyfluidsynth` (installed 1.23.5) and `pip install fluidsynth` (0.2)
2. I followed the solution here, but it didn't work for me. I also think that this wouldn't have been a real solution since it links an older version: [pyFluidsynth 'module' object has no attribute 'Synth'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20022160/pyfluidsynth-module-object-has-no-attribute-synth)
3. I tried `print(fluidsynth.__version__)` which results in `module 'fluidsynth' has no attribute '__version__'`

## Additional Information

I tried to follow this tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/music_generation but I get the error on `waveform = pm.fluidsynth(fs=_SAMPLING_RATE)`. I am using pycharm and I installed all packages into a single virtual environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling `pip uninstall fluidsynth` solved my problem. I think that python maybe was confused by those two because they are named the same.